# Splitting Column to multiple based on row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Trying to split the misc_field_value column into several columns based on the misc_field_id value. The new column names aren't important. Column_1, Column_2 etc.

All of the answers I find are for splitting a column based on a space or values within the same column.

EDIT: I've tried:

`select [10001], [10002], [10003], [10004], [10006]
  from
(
  select misc_field_id, misc_field_value
  from #testtable
)d
  pivot
(
  max(misc_field_value)
  for misc_field_id in ([10001], [10002], [10003], [10004], [10006])
)piv;`

[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/811575)

I guess I'm not sure what aggregate function to use? I'm actually trying to pivot about 5000 rows.

SQL Server 2014

```
+----+---------------+----------------------+
| ID | misc_field_id |   misc_field_value   |
+----+---------------+----------------------+
|  1 |         10001 | REIA EVENT           |
|  1 |         10002 | Test2 REIA           |
|  1 |         10003 | JOE Black            |
|  1 |         10004 | Test Investing, LLC  |
|  1 |         10006 | NC-1                 |
|  2 |         10001 | BROKER               |
|  2 |         10002 | TOM GOULD            |
|  2 |         10004 | TEST Properties, LLC |
|  2 |         10006 | GA-1                 |
|  3 |         10001 | CLIENT REFERRAL      |
|  3 |         10002 | STEFAN TESTER        |
|  3 |         10004 | SIVA EVANS           |
|  3 |         10006 | GA-1                 |
+----+---------------+----------------------+
```

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68UAi.png)

The result I'm looking for would something like:

```
+----+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+----------+
| ID |    Column_1     |   Column_2    |      Column_3       | Column_4 |
+----+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 | REIA EVENT      | Test2 REIA    | TEST INVESTING, LLC | NC-1     |
|  2 | BROKER          | TOM GOULD     | TEST Properties LLC | GA-1     |
|  3 | ClIENT REFERRAL | STEFAN TESTER | SIVA EVANS          | GA-1     |
+----+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+----------+
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yymED.png)

Comment: It seemed like the easiest way to format and I wasn't aware of the lack of embedding until after upload

Comment: Use the {} symbol and then it will put it into a table. A lot of people can't see images and you can't copy and paste the data.

Comment: Add your version of SQL. You will get different answers. New is easier.

Comment: This is a straight pivot

Comment: @TabAlleman -- Nice Link!!! I actually gave a similar answer earlier today

Comment: Using the answer provided doesn't seem to give the desired result

Comment: Ad ID to both selects in your example

Comment: It works! Thankyou